# The mean is different from the mode and the median

Tags: probability, statistics

I am reading a study in which the mean age of a population is 41 years. The mode and median are however both 35 years. I do not have access to the raw data. How I can interpret the difference between the mean and the mode/median?

Comment: Three people: $35,35,53$ years old

Comment: In general, in a data set the mean, median and mode are all different. What is there to interpret? They all attempt to produce a measure of  the average of the data.

Comment: If this is a human population, the only surprising thing is that mode and median are both $35$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael size matters ;)

Comment: In a stable population (with no immigration), the mode would be $0$.  Since the mode is $35$, it looks like the population is failing to reproduce itself.

Comment: This numbers are from a survey. What I'm trying to understand is if I should take the mean or the mode/median as the most representative number for the age

Comment: No one number is truly representative of a data set. Which number is best for your purpose depends on what your purpose is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very primitive example: imagine the dataset has only five entries:

34, 35, 35, 48, 53

The mode and median are 35 and the mean is 41. This basic histogram shows what you might expect: an overshoot of a small number of entries with ages that are much higher than the mode.[image]